# How can i stop the typing animation from repeating but also still show after the animation has completed once?

Tags: css, animation

I'm working on the animation and cannot figure out how I can stop the animation from repeating an infinite amount of times, but also still show after it has completed the animation once. An extra thing as well if you could tell me is that i have 4 different sentences to animate and it would be great if I could make the animations animate one by one then finish and still show.
p.s This is all in css and a lot of changes have been done with copy and paste of used code so i know the animation stuff is repeated

```
type he
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    background-image: url('images/websitesbackground.jpg');
}
.header {
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.logo {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin-top: -10px;
    border: black 3px none;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -180px;
}
.wrapper1 {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.wrapper1 .static-txt {
    color: black;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #121212;
    text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
    0px -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.wrapper1 .dynamic-txts {
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamic-txts li {
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    animation: slide 12s steps(1);
}
@keyframes slide {
    100% {
    top: -160px;
}
}
.dynamic-txts li span {
    position: relative;
}
.dynamic-txts li span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('images/websitesbackground.jpg');
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    animation: typing 3.2s steps(15) infinite;
}
@keyframes typing {
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        margin: 0 -35px 0 35px;
    }
}
.wrapper2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.wrapper2 .static-txt {
    color: black;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #121212;
    text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
    0px -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.wrapper2 .dynamic-txts {
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamic-txts li {
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    animation: slide 12s steps(1);
}
@keyframes slide {
    100% {
        top: -160px;
    }
}
.dynamic-txts li span {
    position: relative;
}
.dynamic-txts li span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('images/websitesbackground.jpg');
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    animation: typing 3.2s steps(15) infinite;
}
@keyframes typing {
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        margin: 0 -35px 0 35px;
    }
}
.wrapper3 {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.wrapper3 .static-txt {
    color: black;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #121212;
    text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
    0px -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.wrapper3 .dynamic-txts {
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: -10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamic-txts li {
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    animation: slide 12s steps(1);
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 2px;
    color: #121212;
    text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
    0px -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
@keyframes slide {
    100% {
        top: -160px;
    }
}
.dynamic-txts li span {
    position: relative;
}
.dynamic-txts li span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('images/websitesbackground.jpg');
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    animation: typing 3.2s steps(15);
}
@keyframes typing {
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        margin: 0 -35px 0 35px;
    }
}
.wrapper4 {
    display: inline-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.wrapper4 .static-txt {
    color: black;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #121212;
    text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 
    0px -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.wrapper4 .dynamic-txts {
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: -50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamic-txts li {
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
@keyframes slide {
    100% {
        top: -160px;
    }
}
.dynamic-txts li span {
    position: relative;
}
.dynamic-txts li span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('images/websitesbackground.jpg');
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
@keyframes typing {
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        margin: 0 -35px 0 35px;
    }
}
@keyframes bubble  {
    0%   { transform:scale(0.5); opacity:0.0; left:0}
     50%  { transform:scale(1.2); opacity:0.5; left:100px}
     100% { transform:scale(1.0); opacity:1.0; left:200px}
}
.img {
    border-radius: 1000px;
    margin-left: 59%;
    margin-top: -44.3%;
    height: 600px;
}
.dynamic-txts {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```
re
```

I have tried all the things i could think of (but its still probably going to be obvious) and i just cant think of anything else, hope someone could help.

Comment: Could you include a sandbox where you've replicated the issue?

Comment: what is type he and re? please put your complete executable code in a snippet and make sure it works properly to show the issue